# How to limit the access of an Azure Active Directory User so that they can only use PowerBI?

Tags: azure-active-directory

I have created a number of new users in AAD but it's for the sole purpose of accessing Power BI.   I don't want them to be able to use Outlook,  Sharepoint or ANY other resource/application.

Is there a way I can configure this in AAD?  Ideally using a group setting so that it applies to all users in the group.

Answer (score 0):

Create a group, add the users into the group.

When you assign O365 subscription to the group, only select Power BI license.

[image]

Don't assign other licenses to them. Except for Power BI, they cannot use other resources.

You can also assign the Power BI license one by one.